# What was the betrayal done by Micheal Roa?

Tags: tsukihime, type-moon

I am just done reading Tsukihime and was looking over some particular things that seem to be unclear and also referred to Wiki for more information around. I read about how Micheal Roa started his incarnations after leaving the Burial Agency but I can't get the part where it is said that he actually betrayed the Church to Mage's Association. I am not sure if I've forget or missed something in the VN, though I reviewed around and I cannot see anything regarding the betrayal of Micheal. I am very curious especially because the page also mentions Riesbyfe to me one of people who were surprised after knowing about it. Or was the betrayal actually just leaving the Church and pursuing the "eternity" by being a Dead Apostle?